# AWS SSM document input parameter stringlist error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I am trying to create one SSM document for taking ec2 snapshots and tagging it via terraform

Code that I have:

```
  resource "aws_ssm_document" "create_snapshots" {
  name            = "create-snapshots"
  document_format = "YAML"
  document_type   = "Automation"
  content = <<DOC
    description: creates snapshots before patching
    schemaVersion: '0.3'
    parameters:
      InstanceId:
        type: AWS::EC2::Instance::Id
        description: (Required) EC2 Instance(s) to restart
      WindowExecutionId:
        type: String
        description: (Required) window execution id
      WindowId:
        type: String
        description: (Required) window id
      Environment:
        type: String
        description: (Required) cluster environment tag
    mainSteps:
      - name: createImage
        action: aws:createImage
        maxAttempts: 3
        inputs:
          InstanceId: '{{ InstanceId }}'
          ImageName: '{{ InstanceId }}_{{global:DATE_TIME}}'
        onFailure: step:SendFailureNotif
        outputs:
          - Name: CustomImageId
            Selector: "CustomImageId"
            Type: String
        nextStep: tagImage

      - name: tagImage
        action: aws:createTags
        maxAttempts: 3
        inputs:
          ResourceIds:
            - ['{{ createImage.CustomImageId }}']
          Tags:
            - Key: 'Date'
              Value: '{{ global:DATE_TIME }}'
            - Key: 'InstanceName'
              Value: '{{ InstanceId }}'
            - Key: 'BackupType'
              Value: 'snapshot'
            - Key: 'BackupDate'
              Value: '{{ global:DATE_TIME }}'
            - Key: 'Environment'
              Value: '{{ Environment }}'
        isEnd: true

DOC
}
```

How ever, its creating AMI image, but Tagging part failing with below error

```
Step fails when it is validating and resolving the step inputs. Failed to resolve ResourceIds to type StringList. Please refer to Automation Service Troubleshooting Guide for more diagnosis details
```

Can some one guide, where the problem is, I verified some documentation examples, but no avail in solution.. yet

Comment: Can you try without square brackets, i..e, `- '{{ createImage.CustomImageId }}'`?

Comment: Actually, the error I got was related to the `onFailure: step:SendFailureNotif` step, since it's not present in the automation document. After I removed it, the apply worked without any errors. If there is that step defined, please add it to the code in the question so the error can be reproduced.

Comment: Also, try this: `<<-DOC`.

Comment: @MarkoE when you removed {{ }} it worked ? Ok will try your suggestion and let you know

Comment: @MarkoE I tried both suggestions , getting `Step fails when it is validating and resolving the step inputs. Failed to resolve input: ResourceIds to type StringList. Cannot Find Value for ResourceIds.. Please refer to Automation Service Troubleshooting Guide for more diagnosis details.`  I find strange thing in documentation for both create image and create tags section.. create image id output can be string, but create tags documentation says "ResourceIds .Type: String List" , may be due to this?

Comment: @MarkoE finally what worked is Selector: "$.ImageId" instead of "CustomImageID"